Can't unlock security & privacy in monterey
I can launch System Preferences but get an error message when clicking on Security & Privacy. If I launch Security & Privacy by option-clicking the System Preferences in the Dock it opens. I can't unlock it to make further changes. I have tried it in Safe Mode and ran Disk Utility from Recovery. No response. Disk Utility runs in Recovery Mode but doesn't solve the main problem. Will reinstalling the OS help?


Are you saying disk utility doesn’t respond in recovery mode? At all? Or you can run first aid and that completes without error, but doesn’t solve the main problem? While you’re editing the post, please ask a direct question like “will reinstalling the OS help?” or “ can I get/trust a good backup in this state?” or whatever you want to do next…

What Mac model is this? Can it be upgraded to a newer version of macOS? Has the preference pane ever worked, and if so, did you change anything just before it stopped working?

Mac Pro (Late 2013), macOS Monterey. it was patched to use Sonoma when I got it but I reformatted the SSD and installed Monterey.

What, if anything, did you restore from a backup after reinstalling Monterey? Reverse migration of data generally doesn’t work.

Starting to see that now. All my work files and photos were restored. I can either patch it again or downgrade to Big Sur

I suggest you pick an OS version that is supported by your hardware, officially and not by a hack, and restore all data from a backup that was made under that version or an earlier one. If you can't do that, restore only documents.

Will use genuine user parts.
